# I'm facing an error on jQuery('video')[0].load(); the data is not loading on the load function: uncaught typeerror

Tags: javascript, jquery, media, lightbox

I am using a lightbox to display images.

I don't know what's wrong. I've tried the slim and the normal version of JQuery

```
 $("#lightboxID").click();
        jQuery('.play-img-cont.videoDiv').show();
        jQuery('.play-img-cont.videoImage').hide();
        $('.video-js, #my-video_html5_api').show();
        // This is where i get the error of uncaught type error
        jQuery('video')[0].load();
        jQuery('video')[0].play();
        var myPlayer = videojs('pubvid');
        myPlayer.play();
        myPlayer.on('ended', function() {
            jQuery('.play-img-cont, .videoImage').show();
            jQuery('.videoDiv').hide();
            this.exitFullscreen();
```

Comment: Should that be `jQuery('#video')` or maybe ` jQuery('.video')`

Comment: What is the full error message? Don't truncate it. Add the message to the question body, not the title. We can guess at the error and solution as RiggsFolly has done, but it'll be clearer if you just tell us precisely what it says, and also please share the relevant HTML as well so we know what you're trying to target with this code. In other words, please make a [mre] of your issue, not just a half-finished one.